# Request mongoDb where

Tags: node.js, mongodb, request

- Hello, I have a little problem with my request mongo. It's not work.
- I want delete one object from MongoDb where isVerified=false and createdAt >=(time now)-(time of creation)=>2
- Thanks for your answers

  ```
  var maintenant = new Date();

  User.remove({
      isVerified: "false",
      createdAt: (((maintenant - user.createdAt) / 1000 / 60) > 2)
  }, function(err) {

  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a perfect case for a [Time-To-Live index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/expire-data/), a [partial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/) one to be precise. Just create the following index and MongoDB will do that removal task automatically for you. There's no need for any custom coding and no need for scheduled activitites, either.

```
db.collection.createIndex( {createdAt: 1}, {
    expireAfterSeconds: 120,
    partialFilterExpression: {
        isVerified: { $eq: false }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have to do a search based on a difference between 2 dates and the result must be a number. If this number >=2 delete the user

Comment: My understanding of your question was that you would want to delete all users that are not verified within 2 minutes after their creation? Am I wrong here?

Comment: Exact, and I use difference bettwen 2 dates

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer: None of that code should be needed. The TTL index I posted will do exactly that for you. Automatically!